# nanopore QC measures on fastq file

Tags: fastq, nanopore, qc

I am working with virus nanopore sequencing data. I have to remove host genome from the reads. I want to run the QC on the fastq file after host genome subtraction. I have used nanoplot. It is slow. I dont have summary.txt. Is there any nanopore read specific qc package which can directly take nanopore fastq files.

Comment: Oh yeh, NanoPlot can be pretty slow when you only have fastq data. I'm happy to look at contributions on how to make it faster. Do you have a machine with multiple cores? Because if your data is split across multiple fastq files then NanoPlot can read those in parallel.

Comment: I have 6 core with 12 threads. How can I split the fastq files and run them in parallel?

Comment: Splitting can be done e.g. with https://fastqsplitter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/, or the Unix split tool.